# "error: use of undeclared identifier" when using a class member variable member fuction called by HTTP response delegate

Tags: c++, delegates, unreal-engine5

I'm saving the value of a token in the class variable `_Token`
The token is added to the request header in `CreateHttpPostRequest`

I make a HTTP request call in `PostToJira` using `CreateHttpPostRequest`, and bind the response to `OnResponseReceived`.

Once i get the response, I call `AddScreenshot`, where I again make a request using `CreateHttpPostRequest`, and add a screenshot to the issue. (You can only add a screenshot to an existing issue, which is why we have to make it first, then add the screenshot in a subsequent call.)

The problem is the value of `_Token` is empty when `AddScreenshot` is called, and I don't know why.

When debugging the watch value shows this: `c++  Stopped in a C++ method, but 'this' isn't available; pretending we are in a generic context. error: use of undeclared identifier '_Token'`

I've tried using BindLambda instead, thinking that maybe Raw was causing the problem, but it looks like there's something about binding the function that's emptying that member variable. Even when I defined the value of `_Token` in the header file in lieu of using `AuthMan::GetToken(_Token)`. The value is still empty.

I also tried `this->_Token` with the same result.

Here are my header and cpp files, sanitized to just show the problem and context:

HtttpUtil.h

```
class HttpUtil
{
public:
    bool PostToJira();
    
private:    
    void AddScreenshot() const;
    
    void OnResponseReceived(FHttpRequestPtr request, FHttpResponsePtr response, bool bConnectedSuccessfully) const;
    
    TSharedRef<IHttpRequest, ESPMode::ThreadSafe> CreateHttpPostRequest() const;
    
    FString _Token = "my_token";
};
```

HttpUtil.cpp

```
bool HttpUtil::PostToJira()
{    
    const FHttpRequestRef request = CreateHttpPostRequest();
    request->OnProcessRequestComplete().BindRaw(this, &HttpUtil::OnResponseReceived);
    request->ProcessRequest();
    return true;
}

void HttpUtil::AddScreenshot() const
{
    const FHttpRequestRef request = CreateHttpPostRequest();
    request->ProcessRequest();
}

void HttpUtil::OnResponseReceived(FHttpRequestPtr request, FHttpResponsePtr response, bool bConnectedSuccessfully) const
{
    AddScreenshot();
}

TSharedRef<IHttpRequest, ESPMode::ThreadSafe> HttpUtil::CreateHttpPostRequest() const
{
    TSharedRef<IHttpRequest, ESPMode::ThreadSafe> request = FHttpModule::Get().CreateRequest();
    request->SetURL("http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two");

    // When this function is called by AddScreenshot(), the _Token value is empty
    UE_LOG(LogConsoleResponse, Warning, TEXT("_Token = %s"), *_Token);
    return request;
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Token`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Comment: I'm guessing your class has been destructed by the time your callback executes. Please show a [mre]

Comment: @Alan Birtles, updated the code

Comment: After testing, I confirmed Alan's guess that the class is being destructed before the callback is happening. Is there a way to keep the class alive until the callback happens?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was running into was that the class was being destructed before the callback was happening. My solution was to not use member variables.